# Force the order of the loop execution nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

```
names = ["jack", "matt", "lisa", "jacob"];
names.forEach(function(name) {
    getID(name);
});
```

The loop gets executed in random order. How to force to execute them in the order:

1. names[0]
2. names[1]
3. names[2]
4. names[3]

Comment: What's `getID`? Can you show us how it's implemented?

Comment: I suppose `getID` is executing asynchronously. Then you should use a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and use one of the serial functions.

Comment: Check my answer and put your getID inside. Is still failing?¿?¿ If it´s still failing, your async method will be getID as they say before

Comment: Just use a regular for loop. Eg: for(var i; i<= name.lenght; i++) {getId(name[i])}

Comment: The loop is NOT executed in random order.  `.forEach()` iterates an array exactly in order. I'm guessing the `getID()` is asynchronous and it finishes in random order.  You will have to show us what `getID()` does in order to delve into that further.

Comment: getID makes http request so the results are shown in random order. Trying to force the execution order, by async or timeouts etc.

Comment: Problem is  with `getID`, please paste that function here.

Comment: Node doesn't really like to be told what order to do things in.  Try hgoebl's suggestion. >names = ["jack", "matt", "lisa", "jacob"];
getID(names[0], function(err0, out0) {
  getID(names[1], function(err1, out1) {
    getID(names[2], function(err2, out2) {
      getID(names[3], function(err3, out3) {
        console.log(out0);
        console.log(out1);
        console.log(out2);
        console.log(out3);
      });
    });
  });
});

Comment: The loop isn't the problem. `getID(name)` is most likely called async, which in this case causes trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your `forEach()` loop is already executed in the order the items appear in the array so the supposition of your question is not correct.

You can see that quite simply like this:

```js
function log(x) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = x;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

var names = ["jack", "matt", "lisa", "jacob"];
names.forEach(function(name) {
    log(name);
});
```

---

So, if you're seeing something out of order, then it is probably because `getID()` includes an asynchronous operation.  Thus you are starting four asynchronous operations at once and though they were started in order, they don't necesarilly finish in order.

If you show us the code for `getID()` and describe what the ordering problem is that you have, then we could likely help you figure out how to sequence the asynchronous results into the proper order.

Promises are a tool of choice for many to help manage the order of asynchronous operations, but we would need to see the `getID()` code in order to know how to recommend more specifically what code to change.